# What does set do in jinja2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have this code:

```
initial: {{ trade_ref }}
{% set saved_trade_ref = (trade_ref or uuid()) %}
```

And later on:

```
{{ saved_trade_ref }} = {{ trade_ref }}
```

I get output similar to:

```
initial:
c7c0cb8b-57bd-4a30-967f-5841438c963f = c7c0cb8b-57bd-4a30-967f-5841438c963f
```

But, on top of creating a variable `saved_trade_ref`, this also sets the value of `trade_ref` to the generated value...  Is this intended?  And if so, is there a way to not do this?

Comment: Are you sure `trade_ref` isn't assigned to somewhere within "And later on"…?

Comment: @deceze 146% sure.

Comment: That's a bit of a low confidence score, innit?

Comment: @deceze well, debugging templates is kind of difficult... I'm quite sure my code doesn't assign to it, but what Jinja does... I don't know.